# Permission denied on IE using window.open()?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, permission-denied

IE is giving me a permission denied error when I use window.open to open a window from a browser button. I do not get the error in Firefox or Chrome. What do I do?

The code:

```
<button type="button" onClick="window.open('https://www.example.com','newWindow');">
My button
</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you running this from `localhost` or `file://`? If so, then that's indeed default behaviour. You could configure that away somewhere in the browser settings forest. But if you're actually running it from a real domain, then IE would in some cases emit this error as well when the URL points to a *different* domain. The browser security settings are apparently configured too strict. To fix this you would need to configure the browser settings accordingly.

This does however not remove the risk that one of your clients using IE would get the very same problem. If you insist in opening an external link in new window, I'd suggest to use an `<a>` with  `target="_blank"` instead (although this attribute is deprecated in HTML; you could make it a `rel="ext"` and run some JS during onload to give `a[rel=ext]` the target attribute).

Comment: I am getting the same error, could you please provide any example or link what you have explained in above answer. As even in my case I need to open new window. I am getting permission denied error only in IE browser not in chrome or firefox.