# Open link in new tab gives permission denied error in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, permissions

I have Intranet asp.net site application that runs under windows authentication account. 
my home page have links to other pages of my site.  In IE, when i open those link in new tab, I get permission denied error.

[image]

if i close the above window and refresh the page, it reloads without any issue.

when i click on debug, i get the following script. I have no idea where it is coming from.

[image]

In other browsers it is working fine. But in IE alone i get this error frequently. targetted IE version is 9.

Please let me know why this is happening only in IE and a solution to overcome it. Any help will be appreciated.

**Note: The error is not due to windows authentication. i changed to anonymous authentication and got the same error.**

There are some possible threads regarding this issue. Unfortunately the solution described in some of those threads doesn't work for me. Most of the other threads says it is a bug with IE and cant be fixed. The workaround given by them is not unique. it is not possible for me to try all those workarounds due to lack of time. There are 173 possible threads regarding this issue. Can you suggest any stable solution in this thread itself?

I am getting the same error even when i browse something on google and open it in new tab. I strongly believe this is because of some browser setting. Is there any possible way to override?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792069/permission-denied-on-ie-using-window-open

Comment: yet another http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960153/permission-denied-with-internet-explorer-and-jquery

Comment: and 172 other questions http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=internet+explorer+access+denied

Comment: and btw, is it just me, or you have a space on the filename? `delivery blu.js` ?

Comment: not space it is underscore.

Comment: Unfortunately the solution described in the two threads you mentioned doesn't work for me. Most of the other threads says it is a bug with IE and cant be fixed. The workaround given by them is not unique. it is not possible for me to try all those workarounds due to lack of time. can you suggest any stable solution in this thread itself?

Comment: i might be able if you setup a jsfiddle reproducing the problem

Comment: @Dementic am getting the same error when i browse something on google and open it in new tab. I strongly believe this is because of some browser setting. Is there any possible way to override?

Comment: so, it is not problem with your code, but a problem with your browser/system. i would try it on another computer to confirm.

Comment: I tried on other systems IE browser too. I didn't get this error in other system.

Comment: can post a minimal code (js mainly) so we could investigate further?

Comment: also, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879192/jquery-iframe-access-denied-in-ie-on-some-pages